# Excel conditional formatting on a shared excel file

Tags: excel

I have a shared excel file in teams with  a team of 10 personnes.

Every body can open the excel file, and put his name in the field A1  and there is a conditional formatting comparing this field A1 to other fields and coloring some other cells.

Every thing works if one person (PERSON1) is on the file.
If another person (PERSON2) open the file at the same time and put his name (PERSON2) in A1 field, it is able to see its data with correct conditional formatting.

But the display for the PERSON1 is no more working, because the conditional formatting is comparing to field A1 which contains now the name of the PERSON2.

Do you have an idea that can solve the issue?

I already tried user defined function in vba to save the name in a global parameter. This allows to store the name in the user session.
This works but it is too slow as the conditional formatting is applied on a lot of cells, each cells calling this UDF.

Best Regards

Comment: Try, instead of opening the file in Teams, use Open in Desktop app

Comment: The same behaviour in desktop app.

Comment: Can't each person have their own file? If it's because of data that needs to be shared then put an workbook_open code that copies the shared data from a "main" file to the users file.

Comment: Possible but will increase maintenance as it will multiply the number of file

Comment: Not really. You can make sure the user files are updated automatically when your master document is updated. But it all depends on how things are set up.